# Angular8 Unittest Router Events

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular8, router

I am trying to test my router event this is what te code in the TS file look like:

```
 constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {


    router.events.subscribe(route => {
        
       // I removed the code because it doesn`t matter for the solution
    });

   }
```

unittest:

```
describe('MainComponent', () => {

    let methodSpy: jasmine.Spy; 
    const eventSubject = new ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>(1);
  
    const routerMock = {
      navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigateByUrl'),
      navigateByUrl: jasmine.createSpy('navigateByUrl'),
      events: eventSubject.asObservable(),
      url: 'test/url',
      createUrlTree: (commands, navExtras = {}) => {},
      serializeUrl: (commands, navExtras = {}) => {}
    }
  
    beforeEach(async(() => {

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule, FormsModule],
        declarations: [],
        providers: [
          { provide: Router, useValue: routerMock},
          { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routerMock},
        ]
      })
      .compileComponents();
    }));
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      methodSpy = spyOn(component, 'AdminPanelStarted');
      //fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  

  
    it('should trigger the router event and hit the function "Panel"', () => {
       
        eventSubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, 'test', 'routeUrl'));
        expect(methodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
```

this is the error I am getting:

[image]

I can`t find the solution. The only thing I want to test is if the correct function have been called after entering the router.events subscription. The observable is triggered but gives the error that startsWith can not be done on undefined. But what is undefined?

Thx a Lot!

Comment: Show the code inside of the `subscribe`. Something.startsWith, something is undefined in that scenario.

Comment: @AliF50 even when there is no code in the SUB I get the error thats why i left it